# R: Identifying an erroneous path setting - which path and where set?

Tags: r, path, environment-variables, user-profile

When I start my R session (under windows 7), I get this error message:

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

I know what the problem is here: Somewhere, there is a directory being set to c:\USERS\something where the \ needs to be a \\ or a /. However, I do not know where it is.

My R_HOME/etc directory has an Rprofile.site file, but no .Rprofile and no .Renviron file.

My HOME directory has neither file.

My HOME/R/win-library/R_Library/base/R directory has an Rprofile file (no period) but no .Rprofile, and no .Renviron

My working directory has neither file.

The R_ARCH directory contains nothing R-related.

I identified all these directories with Sys.getenv().) Of the directories shown there, about 30 display as formed with (single) \'s, while nine are displayed as formed with (single) /'s. There is more than one C: Users directory with the slash going each way.

A computer-wide file search found no instances of either .Rprofile or .Renviron.

So where is this setting? And why does my R installation work at all, with 3/4 of the paths defined in environment variables going one way, and 1/4 of the paths (but still a lot of paths) going the other?

Comment: does `traceback()` immediately after the error occurs give any hints? Also, the output of `sessionInfo()` might be useful.

Comment: `\U` is the prefix to escape Unicode characters, which is what the error is going on about.

Comment: @42 Right. I say that in my second paragraph. The problem is that I do not know where the setting that generates this error is located. It is not in anything I enter at the console -- because this happens before I enter anything at the console -- or anywhere else I can find.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Traceback() says "no traceback available", sessionInfo() just gives me OS and version info, tells me the base packages are loaded, and that tools_3.3.1 is "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)". This error occurs whether R is run stand-alone or under RStudio.

Comment: I'll bet it doesn't happen if you start it from cmd.exe with `r --vanilla`. Find all `.Rdta` or `.Rdata` files and rename them to `bak` version. Same for the `.Rhistory` files. May need to look inside the `.rprofile.site` file and see if it has been taken over by some gremlin. In Windows (and Macs), the "dot-files are usually hidden and you use magical incantations to expose them. The number of directories with solitary backslashes displayed in returns from Sys.getenv() should be zero.

Comment: `sessionInfo()` also reports the version of R in use; paste the output into your question.

Comment: @42 If you want to make this an answer, I'll acept it. The most valuable part was "The number of directories with solitary backslashes displayed in returns from Sys.getenv() should be zero." I figured that some of theme were closer to Windows than R, and didn't feel confident in changing them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet it doesn't happen if you start it from cmd.exe with r --vanilla. Find all .Rdta or .Rdata files and rename them to bak version. Same for the .Rhistory files. May need to look inside the .rprofile.site file and see if it has been taken over by some gremlin. In Windows (and Macs), the "dot-files are usually hidden and you use magical incantations to expose them. The number of directories with solitary backslashes displayed in returns from Sys.getenv() should be zero.